Why is App Center (Snap Store) crashing with "Unable to create GL context?"
Since upgrading to 24.10, I've been encountering some baffling issues with my graphics. The upgrade pulled in the 560.xx Nvidia driver, but installed it alongside the 535 driver (which is the only one that has been working smoothly for me). First, Nautilus, Nextcloud and other applications were having issues, either refusing to start, or crashing on certain operations.
Removed all things nvidia driver and allowed it to use Nouveau and boom! Everything works! Except, that would mean no (very much necessary) advanced graphics abilities. So I had to reinstall the only working version of the driver.
For reasons (apps that aren't ready yet), I'm stuck on X11 for now (lucky me -_-), but I noticed that these issues only seem to occur in X11. Anyway, on to the output:
When running app center, this is what I get:
snap run snap-store
Gtk-Message: 12:54:23.248: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Gtk-Message: 12:54:23.249: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 12:54:23.249: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

(snap-store:563879): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:54:23.274: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:21: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/rolandixor/snap/snap-store/1218/.config/gtk-3.0/colors.css: No such file or directory

(snap-store:563879): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:54:23.299: GTK+ module /snap/snap-store/1218/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 12:54:23.299: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(snap-store:563879): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:54:23.299: GTK+ module /snap/snap-store/1218/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 12:54:23.299: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(snap-store:563879): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:54:23.332: gdk_gl_context_make_current: assertion 'GDK_IS_GL_CONTEXT (context)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): WARNING **: 12:54:23.332: Failed to initialize GLArea: Unable to create a GL context

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.159: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.166: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.173: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.183: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.191: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.196: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.203: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): CRITICAL **: 12:54:25.210: void fl_keyboard_manager_sync_modifier_if_needed(FlKeyboardManager *, guint, double): assertion 'FL_IS_KEYBOARD_MANAGER(self)' failed

(snap-store:563879): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:54:26.625: gdk_gl_context_make_current: assertion 'GDK_IS_GL_CONTEXT (context)' failed

** (snap-store:563879): WARNING **: 12:54:26.625: Failed to uninitialize GLArea: Unable to create a GL context

** (snap-store:563879): WARNING **: 12:54:26.626: Attempted to set message handler on an FlBinaryMessenger without an engine

** (snap-store:563879): WARNING **: 12:54:26.626: Attempted to set message handler on an FlBinaryMessenger without an engine

Clearly, it's having some issue with detecting OpenGL. But why?
Here's my glxinfo:
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.183.06
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.183.06
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 535.183.06
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

Any idea what might be broken, and any idea how to fix it? To be frank, I'm jaded. I'm getting too old for this :)
Edit: Nautilus won't launch anymore either.

As a temporary fix, I decided to disable or remove or (better) "mask" xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service like this:
$ sudo systemctl --user mask xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service

Please, reboot after this.
I am currently using NVIDIA 560 driver, but not in "Performance Mode". See this.
I do have a problem, I mentioned in Occasional screen flicker after upgrade to 24.10 though. :(

Wouldn't this prevent me from using the new file chooser, based on Nautilus? That's a critical feature for me, since often work with digital graphics and need previews when opening files as much as possible.

@RolandiXor  I am not sure. Just test it and if you see any problem just undo it by sudo systemctl --user unmask xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service and reboot.

Just to be clear, restarting this service would effectively do the same as rebooting, correct?

No. Actually we want to stop and never allow it to restart automatically (after a reboot for example). So, rebooting (after mask) has the effect of stopping. And rebooting (after unmask) has the effect of starting.
